# How to embed this flash player?

Tags: html, flash, iframe, embed

I need to embed an m3u8 http live stream (HLS) using a player in flash. I have to embed this url: http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/static/swf/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?src=http://188.165.228.216:51935/mariorossi/DMAX/-156850092_quicklive/playlist.m3u8&plugin_m3u8=http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/static/swf/OSMFHLSPlugin.swf&autoPlay=true&controlBarAutoHide=false in an html page. How can I do so?

Comment: Depending on the video server settings, they may not allow cross domain video play. I believe when using the flash server settings, there is a specific cross domain configuration that can be setup. Just a thought.

Comment: So there is no way to embed this?

Comment: In your case, I don't believe so. This is from "osmfhls.kutu.ru":      "Can I add IFrame with player/plugin on another domain?
No, you can use OSMF HLS Plugin only on domain you were buy license"

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/static/swf/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?src=http://188.165.228.216:51935/mariorossi/DMAX/-156850092_quicklive/playlist.m3u8&plugin_m3u8=http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/static/swf/OSMFHLSPlugin.swf&autoPlay=true&controlBarAutoHide=false" />
</body>
</html>
```